# How to use string operations to make a pretty dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I currently have this function that reads from a txt document, it brings out data and puts it in a dictionary. However I want the dictionary to look pretty and remove the leading and trailing whitespace in each of the string keys, remove all commas and convert them to floats. I want for instance the Neon to look like: `’NEON 20’: 40000`.

This is my print when I run:

```
{'Helium': ['4', '-', '40,000', ';', 'Neon', '20', '-', '40,000', ';',
 'Hydrogen', '-', '35,000'], 'Argon': ['40', '-', '30,000', ';', 'Neon', '22',
 '-', '5,000', ';', 'Argon', '36', '-', '2,000'], 'Methane': ['-', '1000', ';',
 'Ammonia', '-', '1000', ';', 'Carbon', 'Dioxide', '-', '1000']}
```

My code is as following:

```
with open('atm_moon.txt') as document:
    document.readline() #skip unwanted information
    elements={} #empty dictionary of the composition of elements
    for line in document:
        line = line.split()
        if not line: #empty line
            continue
        elements[line[0]]=line[1:]

print(elements
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample content of `atm_moon.txt`?

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

```
all_data = {}
with open('atm_moon.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    # skip header
    next(f_in)
    for line in f_in:
        # skip empty lines
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        for item in line.split(';'):
            item = item.split('-')
            all_data[item[0].strip()] = item[1].strip()

print(all_data)
```

Prints:

```
{'Helium 4': '40,000', 'Neon 20': '40,000', 'Hydrogen': '35,000', 'Argon 40': '30,000', 'Neon 22': '5,000', 'Argon 36': '2,000', 'Methane': '1000', 'Ammonia': '1000', 'Carbon Dioxide': '1000'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am using `pprint` here to make it print the dictionary in a more human-readable form.

Note that you need to iterate also inside each line in order to isolate the elements separated by ";".

Then you can get each data piece into its own variable and use the `replace()` string method to remove the commas.

Finally we use the `float()` builtin function to convert the data type.

```
import pprint

with open('atm_moon.txt') as document:
    document.readline() #skip unwanted information
    elements={} #empty dictionary of the composition of elements

    for line in document:
        if not line.strip():  # skip empty lines
             continue
        for element_info in line.split(';'):
            element_info = element_info.split('-')
            element_name = element_info[0].strip()
            est_composition = float(element_info[1].strip().replace(",", ""))
            elements[element_name] = est_composition

pprint.pprint(elements)
```

Result:

```
{'Ammonia': 1000.0,
 'Argon 36': 2000.0,
 'Argon 40': 30000.0,
 'Carbon Dioxide': 1000.0,
 'Helium 4': 40000.0,
 'Hydrogen': 35000.0,
 'Methane': 1000.0,
 'Neon 20': 40000.0,
 'Neon 22': 5000.0}
```

Please notice that these floats are being automatically displayed with aone decimal place, but you can use string formatting tools to present them without them to the user if needed.